# Is it possible for GC to receive the same data multiple times when using Reliable mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, game-center, gamekit

When sending data to other match players using Game Center, you may use `GKMatchSendDataReliable` or `GKMatchSendDataUnreliable` to send your data.

I use `GKMatchSendDataReliable`. According to Apple's documentation:

> The data is sent continuously until it is successfully received by the
>   intended recipients or the connection times out.

If you reliably send data from `A` to `B`, I suppose that `B` has to tell `A` *"yeah, I received the data"*. If `B` doesn't confirm this, then `A` will keep on sending data indefinitely until `B` confirms it, right?

Now suppose this scenario:

- `A` sends data
- `B` receives data
- `B` has to tell `A` that the data was received successfully

  - However, `B` takes a while to be able to send the confirmation
  - `A` notices that `B` isn't confirming, **so `A` sends the data again**
  - `B` finally sends the confirmation
  - `A` gets the confirmation and stops

In that scenario, technically, `A` sent data twice, even though the first package was successfully delivered. **Does this mean that**

```
-(void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString*)playerID
```

**will be called twice?**

Because if that's the case, this would be potentially dangerous for my game, because most of the data I receive are battle commands, making it possible for someone to attack twice. I would need to implement some sort of lock mechanism to identify each data to determine whether it was already processed or not.

Answer (score 0):

While the network may receive the packet more than once under that scenario, the Game Kit API handles the redundancy for you and you will only receive a single callback to didReceiveData:, there is no risk of it being invoked more than once for each message sent.

With that said however, safe network design should always account for handling unexpected packets.

Comment: Do you have a reference or source for that?

Comment: Through testing, I am the author of Beginning iOS Game Center and Game Kit and Beginning iOS Social Gaming which both cover Game Center development in depth. There is no note of it in the official documentation however.